# Configuring embedded tomcat in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

im new to Java Spring and when i am starting netbeans with a new web project, i have the option to choose a framework. When I'm choosing Spring MVC, i have got an embedded tomcat out of the box. I liked it very much! So easy it can be! But this make it complicated to understand what is happing behind. I want to know, how to create a https connection, without configuring in the tomcat settings. (Or is this the only way?) I tried this one, but than you have to start tomcat manually with the batch-file. When using http-connection und you running your project it usally reachable and you do not need to start tomcat! I dont know how it works, but i think it starts the embedded tomcat and listing to a random port, the url is printing out when starting project. Another question is, where can i change the url name? Now i have this one:

```
 http://localhost:8084/projectname/
```

And i want to give a customer name. Maybe someone answer to this question or post a link with useful information how to configure embedded tomcat. For me it is important to keep the default construction of java spring in netbeans!

[image]

And i want to use the dispatcher.xml,  web.xml -> So don't want to switsch to use tomcat in my javacode! Hope that this is possible!

Thank you very much, Mira.

Comment: The embedded tomcat is configured in the pom.xml file or gradle. You can remove it if you desire so.

Comment: In Netbeans there is default no pom.xml to find! So: i have no pom.file. Isnt the pom-file from a build management tool and it just sets dependencies and no settings?

Comment: If you decide to change the the port number from 8084 to say 8080 you must do the following with application.properties, by adding the
following line: server.port=8000 . This files should be placed under META-INF . But in maven or gradle projects its under src/main/resources.

Comment: try the libraries folder. There should be the jar files. locate the tomcat jar

Comment: Your app doesnt have any pom file because its not a maven project. yes Netbeans supports maven or gradle.

Comment: What should i do with spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar? AND i have no application.properties. I found private.properties and under nbproject/project.properties and i edit this before i posted this question with `server.port=8443` and `j2ee.server.port=8443`! Nothing changed!

Comment: I'am not used to netbeans nor non-maven or non-gradle projects. For that reason i dont want to induce you in error. My advice is to restart your project using spring boot. Go here http://start.spring.io/ select maven project and choose your dependencies. You will receive a zip file. Unzip and import to netbeans. if you have any questions than ask.

Comment: spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar is the embedded tomcat you can remove or modify it

Comment: How can i modify a jar file? Never do this before. I will start a new Spring Project with Maven. And them i hope i will not come back :-D

Comment: You ll love spring boot and maven. less headaches you ll see. If you have questions dont post it here. Simply open a new topic.

Comment: Ok thanks, but for all others! If you have an idea so please tell me.